# Wordpress Shortcode Displaying Above Widget Title

Tags: shortcode, wordpress

I added the following filter in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

This has enabled shortcode in my widgets as expected.

However, the content of the shortcode is now displaying above the title. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I am echoing out via the shortcode:

```
$events_msg = '<div>You have attended <br> <span class="big-num">'. $num_actual_events . '</span> / ' . $num_total_events . ' ' . $event_type . '</br>('. $num_required_events.' required)<br><br></div>';

echo $events_msg;
```

Comment: Without seeing the html/css makeup it'll be hard to tell, but I would check the message to see if the margin is set to a minus value.

Comment: @Howlin The issue is that it needs to `return` not `echo` the results of the shortcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `echo()` in your shortcode rather than `return`'ing the results. If you consider the order that the functions are being called, the `apply_filters( 'widget_text' )` is being run before the actual widget HTML is outputted, thus your `echo` as part of your filter causes it to print out too soon. To correct this `return` instead of `echo` the results.

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode'); 
add_shortcode('events', 'events_shortcode' );
function events_shortcode( $atts, $content=null ){
    // set default attribute values and extract to variables
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'attribute' => 'default_value' ), $atts ) );

    // populate your variables

    $events_msg = '<div>You have attended <br> <span class="big-num">'. $num_actual_events . '</span> / ' . $num_total_events . ' ' . $event_type . '</br>('. $num_required_events.' required)<br><br></div>';

    // return, don't echo
    return $events_msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added the filter to your functions.php, adding the following might have also solved the problem

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop' );
```